# Javascript: Store last value and increment by 1 on next call

Tags: javascript

I have an animation built in Hype 3. I have multiple scenes and at the end of each scene I have a function called. This function has an array of scene names and is used to navigate to the next scene based on the array. I have this working for the first navigation, however, I am unsure how to then go to the next item in the array when the function is next called.

As you can see below, I have an array of two items. When the function is called it navigates to the first item `County1`. When the function is next called it should navigate to `County3`.

At the end of the animation, I will need to run a function that will reset the position as it will loop continuously.

Current Function:

```
function nextScene() {
     var activeCounties = ['County1', 'County3'];
     hypeDocument.showSceneNamed(activeCounties[0]);
     console.log(activeCounties[0]);
}
```

Comment: You'll need to store a variable outside of the function to keep the current array index and use that to reference the scene, e.g. `hypeDocument.showSceneNamed(activeCounties[idx++]);` where `idx` is the variable and the `++` will increment the value by one.

Answer (score 1):

We can create a function with it's own scope and add property `index` into this scope, to track witch scene should be operated

Try this

```js
var nextScene = (function() {
    var index = 0;

    return function () {
     var activeCounties = ['County1', 'County3'];
     // hypeDocument.showSceneNamed(activeCounties[index]);
     console.log(activeCounties[index]);

     // index++ // simpliest way to manage index
     index = index + 1 === activeCounties.length ? 0 : index + 1 // circle. if index is grather than activeCounties.length than index = 0
    }
})();


nextScene() // County1
nextScene() // County3
nextScene() // County1
```

Comment: This works outside of hype but doesn't work within it due to various limitations. Is it possible to do this without the return function? That doesn't seem to work in hype 3 unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Use a global incrementer variable (`i`) to specify which index to point to in the array. Then when you call the function each time, increment this counter.

Here I have also included `% activeCounties.length` to bring the scene count back to zero once all scenes have been shown (allowing you to loop continuously):

```js
var i = 0;
function nextScene() {
     var activeCounties = ['County1', 'County3'];
     //hypeDocument.showSceneNamed(activeCounties[0]);
     console.log(activeCounties[i]);
     
     i = (i + 1) % activeCounties.length;
}

nextScene();
nextScene();
// Modulus brings us back to zero if all scenes reached:
nextScene();
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like almost the definition of [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Generator_functions). It's basically the only way that is like "pausing" the execution of a function and resuming it later. So, without using variables from another scope (like a global variable plainly called `i`), you can do something like:

```
function* nextScene() {
  var activeCounties = ['County1', 'County3'];
  //hypeDocument.showSceneNamed(activeCounties[0]);
  var index = 0;
  while (true) {
    yield activeCounties[index];
    index++;
    if (index == activeCounties.length) {
      index = 0;
    }
  }
}

generateScene = nextScene();

console.log(generateScene.next().value);
console.log(generateScene.next().value);
console.log(generateScene.next().value);
console.log(generateScene.next().value);
console.log(generateScene.next().value);
```

You can see a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ep8wy42f/). Note the asterisk after the `function` keyword. You can also read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).

Also a video I liked, that explains this in the context of a simple game, can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTzwCqoVOPc).

Answer (score 0):

Just to be different I thought I'd show you how to manage it with a class which we'll call `SceneManager`

```js
class SceneManager {
  constructor() {
    this.activeCountries = ['County1', 'County3'];
    this.index = 0;
  }
  nextScene() {
    let activeCountry = this.activeCountries[this.index];
    this.index = (this.index + 1) % this.activeCountries.length;
    return activeCountry;
  }
}

const sm = new SceneManager();

//hypeDocument.showSceneNamed(sm.nextScene())

console.log(sm.nextScene()) // County1
console.log(sm.nextScene()) // County3
console.log(sm.nextScene()) // County1
```

In the constructor, we make a note of the index, 0, and make an `activeCountries` array. Then within that, we have a function, `nextScene()`, that will return the active country and also move the index along the array list.